# Why would my RX6600 cards show the driver but not the model ? all four RX580 show correctly and work as expected

Tags: drivers, 20.04, graphics, amdgpu

I am running an eight card rig with four RX580 on AMD 21.40.01, The latest version, recently i added two RX6600. I must admit, I expected them to just "be there" when i rebooted the system. This is not the case, though. With much messing around, I broke Linux and had to reload from scratch, where I then added all repositories drivers etc. `CLINFO` now "sees" the cards; all four RX580 as before, all working perfectly. It "sees" the two RX6600, too, but does not display the model number; only the driver.

This is the basic output from `CLINFO`:

```
clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL)  Success (6)
    Platform Name                                 Clover
    Device Name                                   AMD DIMGREY_CAVEFISH (LLVM 13.0.0, DRM 3.43, 5.11.0-44-generic)
    Device Name                                   AMD Radeon RX 580 2048SP (polaris10, LLVM 13.0.0, DRM 3.43, 5.11.0-44-generic)
    Device Name                                   AMD Radeon RX 580 2048SP (polaris10, LLVM 13.0.0, DRM 3.43, 5.11.0-44-generic)
    Device Name                                   AMD Radeon RX 580 2048SP (polaris10, LLVM 13.0.0, DRM 3.43, 5.11.0-44-generic)
    Device Name                                   AMD DIMGREY_CAVEFISH (LLVM 13.0.0, DRM 3.43, 5.11.0-44-generic)
    Device Name                                   AMD Radeon RX 580 2048SP (polaris10, LLVM 13.0.0, DRM 3.43, 5.11.0-44-generic)
```

I suspect, as it is not showing the model number, that I have either done something incorrectly or missed something important.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Here is some more info:

```
Graphics: Device-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] 
driver: amdgpu
v: 5.11.32.21.40
Device-2: Advanced Micro Devices
[AMD/ATI] Polaris 20 XL [Radeon RX 580 2048SP]
driver: amdgpu 
v: 5.11.32.21.40
```

In the above, the first device it lists is the RX6600 and the second is the RX580 and yet only shows the correct info for the RX580 and not for the RX6600, THIS has to be some sort of mistake i am making with the drivers.... (for clarity, `inxi -g` does list all six cards)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu have you re-installed?

Comment: Apologies, didnt mention it 20.04, same as i was using previously

Comment: Hi, thought i'd add the following, i'm now even more convinced ive missed something...
Graphics:  Device-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] driver: amdgpu v: 5.11.32.21.40 
           Device-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Polaris 20 XL [Radeon RX 580 2048SP] driver: amdgpu v: 5.11.32.21.40

Comment: In the above, the first device it lists is the RX6600 and the second is the RX580 and yet only shows the correct info for the RX580 and not for the RX6600, THIS has to be some sort of mistake i am making with the drivers.... (for clarity, inxi -g does list all six cards but space is limited here...)

Comment: It does not support properly yet.